cuda dynamic allocate in device,and copy to device, is it possible
I pass a struct pointer to a device function, and this device function edits this pointer.
struct:
struct substruct{
    int main;
    int sub;
};

struct mainstruct{
    int main;
    int sub;
    substruct* subs;
};

device function:
__global__ void update(mainstruct* target){
    printf("in device: target: %d/%d/%d\n", target->main, target->sub, target->subs);
    substruct *sub = new substruct();
    sub->main = 5;
    sub->sub = 5;
    target->subs = sub;
    printf("in device: sub created/allocated: %d/%d\n", sub->main, sub->sub);
}

and this is main:
int main(){
    mainstruct *main = new mainstruct();
    main->main = 10;
    main->sub = 10;
    main->subs = nullptr;

    mainstruct* main_device;
    handleerr(cudaMalloc(&main_device, sizeof(mainstruct)));
    handleerr(cudaMemcpy(main_device, main, sizeof(mainstruct), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    
    update << <1, 1 >> > (main_device);
    handleerr(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    handleerr(cudaGetLastError());

    handleerr(cudaMemcpy(main, main_device, sizeof(mainstruct), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    substruct *subs = new substruct();
    handleerr(cudaMallocHost(&subs, sizeof(substruct)));
    handleerr(cudaMemcpy(subs, main->subs, sizeof(substruct), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    main->subs = subs;

    printf("done");
}

I keep encountering an error at the line :
handleerr(cudaMemcpy(subs, main->subs, sizeof(substruct), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
how can I correctly copy memory that was dynamically allocated??

you cannot do this.  when you did substruct *sub = new substruct(); in device code, you created an allocation that cannot be used or participate in a host API cudaMemcpy call.  That data will need to be in an allocation provided from the host API (e.g. cudaMalloc) before it can be used in a host API copy call (e.g. cudaMemcpy).  There are a variety of questions like this already on the cuda SO tag.  here is one.

ooohh , its impossible.. thanks. have a good day
